# Factorial Series Compute

Tags: calculus, contest-math

Given $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\sum_{j=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(j^n)(j!)}=a+be$ where $a$ and $b$ are integers, find $a$ and $b$.

Comment: Note that $ e=\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{j!}$

Answer (score 6):

$$\sum_{n=2}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{j^n}=\frac{1}{j(j-1)},\tag{1}$$
hence the problem boils down to computing:
$$\begin{eqnarray*} \sum_{j\geq 2}\frac{1}{j(j-1)j!}&=&\sum_{j\geq 2}\frac{1}{(j-1)j!}-\sum_{j\geq 2}\frac{1}{j\cdot j!}\\&=&\frac{1}{2}+\sum_{j\geq 2}\left(\frac{1}{j\cdot(j+1)!}-\frac{1}{j\cdot j!}\right)\\&=&\frac{1}{2}-\sum_{j\geq 2}\frac{1}{(j+1)!}\\&=&\color{red}{3-e}.\tag{2}\end{eqnarray*} $$